# Xamarin forms Preferences reset when app update

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-play, preferences

I'm using Preferences to save service IP but when i update app this values reset.

```
Preferences.Set("myServiceIP", serviceIP);
```

I take a new apk from visual studio and install to my phone then these preferences reset.
I need to save at least this service IP. I want to learn this when i install my app from Google Play and update from Google Play these preferences reset or keep at this situation ?
If update won't reset my preferences from my device its ok but if this reset also, this going to be problem.
Can someone give me information about this ?

Comment: You can double-check whether the value of variable `serviceIP` has changed and where you call function `Preferences.Set("myServiceIP", serviceIP);`  to set the stored value.

Comment: When I install app to my phone situation is like uninstall and install. So, preferences delete. I want to learn when I release new update on Google play this values of preferences will delete again ?

Comment: If you uninstall your app, this value of preferences will delete.

Comment: What about update on google play ? Does phone keep them ?

Comment: If your app is updated but doesn't change this value, it won't change. But if this value is re-stored by your app, the stored value will definitely change.

Comment: Thank you Jessie Zhang, your answers help me a lot.

Comment: XF Essentials Preferences internally uses SharedPreferences on Android and UserDefaults on iOS, These are only maintained by your application as long as you don't delete the app if you were to update your application without deletion your preference will stay. Once you delete it it is gone forever even if you reinstall the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a summary, I will post an answer.

From document [Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=android), we could find that:

> Uninstalling the application will cause all Preferences to be removed,
> with the exception being apps that target and run on Android 6.0 (API
> level 23) or later that use Auto Backup. This feature is on by default
> and preserves app data including Shared Preferences, which is what the
> Preferences API utilizes.

So, if you uninstall your app, this value of preferences will delete. If you didn't uninstall your app and update your app directly, the previous `Preferences` data will be kept. Whether the stored value changes depends on whether you reset the value of variable `serviceIP` that you want to store to `Preferences`.